# How to fix 'Undefined Function or Variable' in matlab?

Tags: matlab, function, variables, undefined

I have defined a bunch of constants. I want to use these in local functions.
The function can't access these values and I get the error 
Undefined function or variable 'g'.

I have tried shifting the position of the functions
Also tried to make the constants global so every local function knows them

```
**% Define constants** 
  K=0.5; % minor loss coefficient (square edged)
  g=9.8; % gravity in m/s2


**%call function**
f1= 2 (value obtained from external function)  
 v1=velocity1(f1);

**% define function**
 function v1=velocity1(f)
 v1= sqrt((2*g*h)/(1+(f*(L./D))+K));
 end

>> LvsQ_plot
Undefined function or variable 'g'.

Error in LvsQ_plot>velocity1 (line 48)
v1= sqrt((2*g*h)/(1+(f*(L./D))+K));

Error in LvsQ_plot (line 31)
v1=velocity1(f1);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple approaches passing constants to MATLAB functions

Defining variables as `global` is a simple solution.
Using `global` makes the variable "visible" to all functions and scripts. The downside of using `global`, is that it's not extendable, and prevents code reuse.
From academic software engineering perspective, you shouldn't use global variables at all. Assuming your code is used for solving a specific problem and not going to be extended or reused, using `global` is permitted.

Using `global`:
Declare the constants as global before initialization:

```
global K g
K=0.5; % minor loss coefficient (square edged)
g=9.8; % gravity in m/s2
```

Declare the variables as global in any function that uses them:

```
function v1=velocity1(f)
    global K g
    v1= sqrt((2*g*h)/(1+(f*(L./D))+K));
end
```

---

Using nested functions:
Instead of using `global`, you can use "nested functions" approach - an inner function can access the variables of an outer function.
Define your main script as a function, and `velocity1` as an inner function:

```
function main()
%main is the outer function, and velocity1 is an inner function

K=0.5; % minor loss coefficient (square edged)
g=9.8; % gravity in m/s2
h=1;L=3;D=4;

f1= 2; %(value obtained from external function)  
v1=velocity1(f1);

    %Inner function:
    function v1=velocity1(f)
        v1= sqrt((2*g*h)/(1+(f*(L./D))+K));
    end
end
```

---

Passing a struct of parameters to the function:
A common solution is MATLAB is passing a struct with constant parameters to all functions that uses them:

```
param.K=0.5; % minor loss coefficient (square edged)
param.g=9.8; % gravity in m/s2
param.h=1;param.L=3;param.D=4;

f1= 2; %(value obtained from external function)  
v1=velocity1(f1, param);

function v1=velocity1(f, par)
    K = par.K;
    g = par.g;
    h=par.h;L=par.L;D=par.D;
    v1= sqrt((2*g*h)/(1+(f*(L./D))+K));
end
```

There are other approaches, but I can't list them all...